# Access 2007 sql editor

Tags: ms-access

Is there an ACCESS 2007 JET SQL editor or client (not sure the right term is) that can be used to code Access Jet SQL queries? It is very difficult to write SQL queries in ACCESS 2007 since it's like basically typing in notepad without any special text formatting for keywords or commands for example. Its hard to write and read... Any suggestions or tools that I can use to make this process easier?

Comment: the only other alternative I have come up with is using Word and then copying and pasting into Access Sql Window...

Comment: No, no, no, not Word. Word is not a code editor, it's a (rich) format editor. It wasn't designed for code editing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many tools and ways better ways to do SQL editing  for Access 2007 other then using msword , at least i would use [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)

below are tools i used and are good

1. [RazorSQL](http://www.razorsql.com/features/access_editor.html)
2. [SQuirreL SQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=screenshots)

here is a 2 [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823687/free-sql-code-editor) and [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418960/managing-and-debugging-sql-queries-in-ms-access) in Stackoverflow similar to your issue

but if you want my opinion to this problem, the best thing i suggest is to use SSMS and add a [linked server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213778%28SQL.80%29.aspx) to your Access file, i like SSMS

Answer (score 3):

I realize this question is over 3 years old now, but I wrote an MS-Access add-in called Access SQL Editor ([link](https://www.fieldeffect.info/purchase/)), because I write a lot of SQL in Access.

It's not free, but it's very inexpensive.  If you find it useful but can't afford it, or you really don't want to buy it, [contact me](http://fieldeffect.info/wp/access-sql-editor-documentation/) and I'll send you a free license.

Features

- Syntax Highlighting
- SQL Comments
- Line numbers
- Search-and-replace, with regular expression syntax
- Hotkeys
- Automatic query formatting
- Supports pass-through queries
- Works with Access 2002-2016 (it's activated from the "Add-Ins" menu in Access)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I tried both application from the accepted answer and this add-in is by far better.